# Is there any easy way to move multiple tables in Oracle which has around 5TB data to ADLS

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a requirement where I need to move data from multiple tables in Oracle  to ADLS.
The size of data is around 5TB. These files in ADLS, I might use it in future to connect Power BI.
Is their any easy and efficient way to do this.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `Lookup` activity and `ForEach` in Azure Data Factory.

Create a table or file to store the **list of table names** which needs to be extracted.

- Use **Lookup Activity** get the **tables list**.
- Pass the list to **ForEach** activity and by looping each table copy the current `item()` from oracle to ADLS.
- In **ForEach**, settings->Items, add the following code in the Add Dynamic Content.

  `@activity('Get-Tables').output.value`
- Add a **Copy activity inside ForEach activity**.
- In Copy data activity, source > Query and Input the following code:

  `SELECT * FROM @{item().Table_Name}`
- Now add the **sink dataset(ADLS)** and Execute your pipeline.

Please refer [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle?tabs=data-factory#create-a-linked-service-to-oracle-using-ui) to know about the creation of linked services for Oracle.
Please go through this [article](https://www.modern-dataengineering.com/post/how-to-copy-multiple-tables-in-azure-data-factory) **by Sean Forgatch in MODERN DATA ENGINEERING** if you face any issues in the process.